# Top-left point of rotated RectangleGeometry in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation

I'm given the rotated `RectangleGeometry` and I need to find the top-left and bottom-right points. What would be the fastest way to accomplish that?

Please notice, that I don't want these points for AABB or something - I just need the rectangle's points.

Thank you in advance for the clues!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Rect` property holds the points of the `RectangleGeometry`.  It's not clear to me if the `Rect` reflects any rotation, or if it's the un-rotated points.  If it's the un-rotated points then you'll have to take the points from the `Rect` and transform them using the `Transform` property of the `RectangleGeometry`.

Comment: @Jim, you are definitely right. These points are of unrotated rect, thus we need to transform them (that is what I have just checked). Thanks!

Comment: @Jim, I just wonder if there is a possibilty of getting the original points in case of the ellipse (I mean EllipseGeometry)? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Jamie: You could apply the inverse of the transform and then get the points from the `Bounds` property.

Comment: @Jamie: It occurs to me that you already have all you need to find the initial points for an `EllipseGeometry`.  The top left will be at `Center.X - RadiusX, Center.Y - RadiusY`.  The other points are computed similarly.  That will give you a rect from which you can compute size.  Note that it won't give you the initial points if `Transform` includes any kind of translation, skew, sizing, etc.